# Android tabhost missing when nfc scanned

Tags: java, android, image, dynamic, nfc

When I scan my NFC tag, my application fires up and does what it have to do , but the tabhost goes missing. The mainactivity.java is where I initialize the tabhost with 3 tabs and this following first part of the code is one of the tab in which I utilize the NFC reading function. Is this because of the pendingintent? I don't really know how to fix it, do I have to implement the 3 tabs in every activity layout?

My code:

```
package com.example.ponpon;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.os.PatternMatcher;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@TargetApi(10)
public class CouponManager extends Activity {

        private static final String TAG = "NFCReadTag";
        private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
        private IntentFilter[] mNdefExchangeFilters;
        private PendingIntent mNfcPendingIntent;
        public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "PrefFile";

        private int[] images = new int[11];

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.coupon_layout);

            //List of images
            images[0]=R.drawable.cp0;
            images[1]=R.drawable.cp1;
            images[2]=R.drawable.cp2;
            images[3]=R.drawable.cp3;
            images[4]=R.drawable.cp4;
            images[5]=R.drawable.cp5;
            images[6]=R.drawable.cp6;
            images[7]=R.drawable.cp7;
            images[8]=R.drawable.cp8;
            images[9]=R.drawable.cp9;
            images[10]=R.drawable.cp10;

            //Restore preferences 
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("storedInt", 0);

            //Image to use depending on coupon collected
            final ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            if(storedPreference!=10)
            {
                img.setImageResource(images[storedPreference]);
                img.invalidate();
            }
            else
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setTitle("Coupon Redemption");
                builder.setMessage("Redeem Your Coupon?");
                builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                        editor.putInt("storedInt", 0); // value to store
                        editor.commit();    
                        img.setImageResource(images[0]);
                        img.invalidate();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        img.setImageResource(images[10]);
                        img.invalidate();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }


            //Check and send Intent from NFC tag discovered
            mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

            mNfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
                    getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                    /*| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP*/), 0);


            IntentFilter coupontag = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
            coupontag.addDataScheme("http");
            coupontag.addDataAuthority("www.ichatime.com", null);
            coupontag.addDataPath(".*", PatternMatcher.PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB);

            mNdefExchangeFilters = new IntentFilter[] { coupontag };

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if(mNfcAdapter != null) {
                mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mNfcPendingIntent,
                    mNdefExchangeFilters, null);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, No NFC Adapter found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            if(mNfcAdapter != null) mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("storedInt", 0);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("storedInt", storedPreference); // value to store
            editor.commit();    
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();

            // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
              // All objects are from android.context.Context
                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("storedInt", 0);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("storedInt", storedPreference); // value to store
                editor.commit();    
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();

            // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
              // All objects are from android.context.Context
                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("storedInt", 0);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("storedInt", storedPreference); // value to store
                editor.commit();    
        }

        @Override
           public void onBackPressed() {
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("storedInt", 0);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("storedInt", storedPreference); // value to store
            editor.commit();    
               super.onBackPressed();
           }

        @Override
        protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
            super.onNewIntent(intent);      
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("storedInt", 0);

            if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                NdefMessage[] messages = null;
                Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
                if (rawMsgs != null) {
                    messages = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                        messages[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                    }
                }
                if(messages[0] != null) {
                    String result="";
                    byte[] payload = messages[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
                    // this assumes that we get back am SOH followed by host/code
                    for (int b = 1; b<payload.length; b++) { // skip SOH
                        result += (char) payload[b];
                    }
                    if (result.contains("ichatime.com"))
                        {
                        final ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


                        /*if (storedPreference!=10)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Coupon collected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            storedPreference++;
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                            editor.putInt("storedInt", storedPreference);
                            img.setImageResource(images[storedPreference]);
                            img.invalidate();
                        }*/
                            if (storedPreference==10)
                            {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                                builder.setCancelable(false);
                                builder.setTitle("Redeem Your Coupon?");
                                builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
                                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                    {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                                        editor.putInt("storedInt", 0); // value to store
                                        editor.commit();    
                                        img.setImageResource(images[0]);
                                        img.invalidate();
                                    }
                                });
                                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        img.setImageResource(images[10]);
                                        img.invalidate();
                                    }
                                });
                                builder.show();
                            }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Coupon collected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            storedPreference++;
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                            editor.putInt("storedInt", storedPreference);
                            editor.commit();
                            img.setImageResource(images[storedPreference]);
                            img.invalidate();
                        }}
                    else 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong tag detected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    //Debugging Mode to see what is contained in the tags.
            //          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tag Contains " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

***and also, my main activity:***

```
package com.example.ponpon;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Coupon Manager");
        spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        spec1.setIndicator("Coupons");
        Intent CouponsIntent = new Intent(this, CouponManager.class);
        spec1.setContent(CouponsIntent);

        TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Help");
        spec2.setIndicator("Help");
        spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        Intent SettingsIntent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
        spec2.setContent(SettingsIntent);

        TabSpec spec3=tabHost.newTabSpec("Write[Vendor]");
        spec3.setIndicator("Write\n[Vendor]");
        spec3.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        Intent HelpIntent = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
        spec3.setContent(HelpIntent);

        tabHost.addTab(spec1);
        tabHost.addTab(spec2);
        tabHost.addTab(spec3);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a close look at your logic: you have

```
if (storedPreference!=10) {
    ...stuff... (including storedPreference++)
}
if (storedPreference==10) {
    ...stuff...
} else {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("storedInt", 10);
    img.setImageResource(images[10]);
    img.invalidate();
}
```

You should consider replacing the contents of the `else` block with the `storedPreference!=10` block, then getting rid of that first block.  All you need is `if storedPreference==10` and `else`.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks! One more thing, when I scan a NFC tag with the phone, my tabhost goes missing (using tabs) and I have to resort to pressing the back button on the phone. This will cause my coupons collected to be 0 back. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Thanks! I have solved the problem about the images not being manipulated. Now I need to settle the back button showing history and also, when the coupons collected have been maximized, the dialogue box does not show and onRestart, it shows back 0 coupons collected but when tag is scanned, no coupons are getting collected. I'm guessing something is wrong with the code involving the storedPreference==10

Comment: Glad that helped.  Are those other things still a problem for you?  If so, feel free to post another question.  I didn't see any references to your tabs in the code.

Comment: The tabs are in my mainactivity.java. It contains the tabhost, nothing else. I have 3 tabs, and each of the tabs are another activity. Is the tabhosts disappearing when NFC is scanned because of the pending intent in which only this activity is launched on top of the others , whereby making it appear full screen. (mainactivity is neglected) if so is there a workaround?

Comment: i updated my question with the mainactivity containing the tabhosts. any idea on how i may proceed to prevent the tabhost from going missing when i scan a nfc tag? thanks!

Comment: I think you have the wrong idea going on in your code.  Typically you don't put new Intents into your tabs, but instead, you set the tab layout to be a series of GUI objects, similar to the way you'd normally make XML for any one of your activities.  If you need a higher level of interaction, consider using Fragments.  With Fragments, you can easily consider different layouts depending on screen size, density, etc. so you're always maximizing the screen layout.  Please look into Fragments for Android and post a separate question if you have any problems so whoever answers it will get credit.